# Redefine standard css colors

Tags: jquery, css, colors, default, redefine

Is there a javascript/jQuery function that would Redefine the standard css color names? (Something you could simply copy/past into your projects.)

example:

```
<div id="example"></div>

<style>

#example { background: red; }

</style>

<script>

if(true) {
    function redefineColor () {
    var backgroundColor = $("*").css("background");   //select all elements

    if( backgroundColor == "#FF0000" ) {              //red color.
      $(this).css("background","#DC143C");              //other shade of red.
    } else { return false}
    redefineColor();
}
</script>
```

greetings

Comment: No there is not, and the browser generally doesn't return hex, but rgb(a) for colors, which makes it hard to work with in javascript

Comment: That sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: A more straightforward solution: create a JS object with your desired names as keys and the appropriate hex/rgba as values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/901048/blazemonger, that sound good. Any idea where i could find some more info about this.

Comment: Big flaw in your `get all elements` concept. A value getter can only return one value, and that will be the first matching element of the selector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl So, that would mean that the function would have to repeat itself. To find the next matching element, after the next, etc

Comment: @Blazemonger <- that's how you ping by the way .............

Comment: @adeneo, im getting there :)